# Why model property $valid lost after angular.copy

Tags: angularjs

I have property `$scope.EditedModel` in Controller, and default it undefined. But this property has `$scope.EditedModel.$valid`.

[image]

I have action in controller, which assign value to `$scope.EditedModel`:

`$scope.setEditedId = function(id){
        $scope.EditedModel = angular.copy($filter('filter')($scope.startPages, { id: id })[0]);
    }`

And after this action my model don't have $valid property.

[image]

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you requiring ngModelController? Please show us how this editedModel is bound to your scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning to `$scope.EditedModel` the property of `$scope.startPages`, maybe you should use also `angular.extend` to have previous values...

something like:
`$scope.setEditedId = function(id) {
    $scope.EditedModel = angular.extend(
        $scope.EditedModel,
        angular.copy($filter('filter')($scope.startPages, { id: id })[0])
    );
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case, it's better to use the extend function:

```
angular.extend($scope.EditedModel, $filter('filter')($scope.startPages, { id: id })[0])
```